# ExtJS4 - Proxy, Store, Model, Autoload - whats the magic?

Tags: model, proxy, extjs4, store

I have a proxy defined on my Model.

I have a store defined pointing to the Model, no proxy, as I want it to use the one defined on the Model.

`store.autoLoad`: true ain't working

I have to explicitly call from my Controller

```js
var store = this.getMyStore();
store.load();
```

Is this expected behavior?

1. isn't this what autoload is for?
2. will it only work when the proxy is defined on the store?

**Code:**

**model/MyThing.js**

```js
Ext.define('MyApp.model.MyThing', {

  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

  fields: ['id', 'reference'],

  proxy:
  {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'MyThings'
  }
});
```

**store/MyThings.js**

```js
Ext.define('MyApp.store.MyThings', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
  autoLoad: true,
  autoSync: false,
  model: 'MyApp.model.MyThing'
});
```

Comment: make sure you have `autoLoad` and not `autoload`. It should automatically load the store once you launch application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this is a bit of a newbie thing. I've been a bit of an eager beaver.

I was looking at the store before it had completed loading (as its asynchronous).

Best practice is to subscribe to the load() function's callback and then do something...

```
store.load({
    scope   : this,
    callback: function(records, operation, success) {
        //the operation object contains all of the details of the load operation
        console.log(records);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't show how you're creating the store.
You should see an HTTP GET request in FireBug (assuming you're using FireFox and have it) as soon as you call:

```
Ext.create('MyApp.store.MyThings');
```

I added your code to my app and got the expected results, so it should be working.

**UPDATE:**

In response to your own posted answer, you can supply that config object as `autoLoad` (rather than `autoLoad: true`) to get the same functionality without having to explicitly call `store.load()`

Comment: Yeah i can see that has uses too